# Can't append li into ul with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Been going through these 3 lines for the past 15 minutes, but i just don't see it...
EDITED CLASS NAMES.
html

```
<div class="parent" >
<ul class="child" style="height:auto !important"></ul>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".parent ul").append('<li>wtf</li>');
});
```

I've tried appending to  .child, to .parent ul.child
no luck

Edit: when i look at the fiddle in the answer bellow, it works. I copy the same code and it fails. I tried all browsers. same thing.

Comment: Class names shouldn't start with numbers.

Comment: Although HTML5 has been more "forgiving" @j08691 and it actually works here - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/9dKWB/

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your browser's console? Perhaps one that says something like $ is undefined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".1 ul").append('<li>wtf</li>');
});
```

Works fine.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rz4Av/2/)

Problem is not in code, you added to your question. Are you sure you included jquery library?

Please, use firebug tool or any other tool to debug your code (chrome developers tools (CTRL+SHIFT+J), developers tools in ie (possibly F12), developers tools in Firefox (CTRL+SHIFT+J). You can find some good answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/988363/2898694) (read answers).

### In additional:

As mentioned in comments to your question (and at [w3cschools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp) website):

> Do NOT start a class name with a number!

So use this:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".parent ul").append('<li>wtf</li>');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parent" >
<ul class="child" style="height:auto !important"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @user3638287 I added demo which shows that your code is working fine (even with bad class name). Problem is not there.

Comment: I have other names for classes. I used numbers to simplify, but i'll keep it in mind. thanks. What i don't get is when i look at fiddle you provided, it works. I copy the same code into separate fiddle and it fails

Comment: @user3638287 - Check your browser's console for errors.

Comment: @user3638287 Yes, I updated my question, but forget to said about here. I added some suggestions about how to debug your js code. So do it.

Comment: there is an error in console, but it's in a different file and a different script. Yes, i'm sure jquery is included. There is another jquery script, and it works fine.

Comment: What error? If you have some errors in jQuery console you have to solve problem. It can cause this error. + check selectors again. It is okay? Do it again. Still okay? Take a rest then :) The problem is not here, as I said. Your code is working fine.

Comment: No. just went with a different solution... But thank you for your time!